# Saving multiple screenshots with adb

Tags: android, macos, adb

I can save screenshots from an Android using `adb exec-out screencap -p > ~/Desktop/screen.png`. My problem with this is that it overwrites the last saved image when I take a new one. How can we save multiple images so that it saves the newest image with a number, or something, like `screen-2.png`?

I've looked around and am not seeing any answered questions on this particular issue, but if I missed it, please point me in that direction.

Thank you.

Comment: If you manually execute a command that includes a redirection into a certain file then this s file is always used. What prevents you from creating a small shell script (bash, zsh whatever you prefer) that generates a file name may be based on current time and date and then executes the adb command using that generated name? There should be plenty of similar questions depending on what shell you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create a script as recommended in the comments, then

```
adb exec-out screencap -p > $(mktemp -t screen)
```

would be the closest using random names.